# Compiling examples/standalone_example.cpp of MySQL Connector/C++ fails

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I downloaded the source of MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.4 and was able to compile and install it. However, compiling the example fails.

```
clang++ -o test_install -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/cppconn -lmysqlcppconn standalone_example.cpp
```

fails with

```
standalone_example.cpp:118:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXAMPLE_FUNCTION'
            cout << "(" << EXAMPLE_FUNCTION << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

This is the link to the mysql doc for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-unix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standalone_example.cpp is missing an include. Add ...

```
#include "examples.h"
```

...and it compiles. With some warnings.